# Inequality involving $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: arithmetic

I need some help with the following problem:

> Show that for any pair $(a,b)$ of positive integers, $\dfrac{a+2b}{a+b} < \sqrt{2} < \dfrac{a}{b}$.

I tried squaring both sides of the inequality, but I was not able to solve it.

Comment: This is false, take $ a = b = 1 $, for instance.

Comment: Okay, re:downvote(s).  The "duplicate" as referred above: "Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Show that $\sqrt{2}$ always lies between $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{a+2b}{a+b}$. Please give the easy solution as possible" received **three upvotes.**  This question is superior to that question (just quoted) in terms of asking and not telling..  So why the downvotes here, but not there?

Comment: Try looking at $$\dfrac{a+2b}{a+b} > \sqrt{2} > \dfrac{a}{b}$$

Comment: @yumiko this is a case which reveals the non-uniform standards in accepting a question, and rejecting it.  As you see in the third comment, voting is decidedly arbitrary at this site.  So **don't take the inconsistent standards at this site personally!**